# $\sigma$-$\sigma$-compactness is $\sigma$-compactness?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I mean, if $X=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}K_n$ where each $K_n$ is $\sigma$-compact, then $X$ is $\sigma$-compact?

I'm not sure if a countable union of countable unions is still a countable union.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable

Comment: I seem to recall that a year or so ago someone asked here how to prove that a union of countably many countable sets is countable and I, and several others, answered.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449970/the-union-of-a-sequence-of-countable-sets-is-countable) and  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603456/prove-that-the-union-of-countably-many-countable-sets-is-countable).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker and T.Bongers, Guys, please read again. I'm not asking if a countable union of countable sets is countable. If what I wrote of countable unions is not clear, the real answer is above. I'm asking if $X$ is a countable union of $\sigma$-compact sets then $X$ is $\sigma$-compact. I wrote nothing about countable sets.

Comment: @Talexius Let $I$ be some index set and for each $n$, $C_n\subseteq I$ be countable. Then $\bigcup_n \Big(\bigcup_{i\in C_n} U_i\Big)=\bigcup_{i\in\bigcup_n C_n}U_i$.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelGreinecker ! If you post your reply I could select it as the answer.

Comment: @Talexius I think it is more productive if you post it as answer.